# Relative prime message in RSA encryption.

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Why has the message $P$ to be relative prime to $n$ in RSA encryption?

This should be fault?
\begin{align}
C &\equiv P^e \pmod{n} \\
&\equiv 101112^{11111357} \pmod{9998000099} \\
&\equiv 3316546434 \pmod{9998000099}
\end{align}

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.
I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.  It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: There is no need for the message to be relatively prime to the modulus in RSA.  Why do you think this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ can be any number $< n$, encryption will work. It will produce a valid ciphertext for which decryption still works.

It's also a very small probability (for realistically sized $n$) that this would happen anyway. If anyone were to randomly generate some $P$ and notice that the gcd of $P$ and $n$ was not $1$, that person would have factored $n$ and broken this RSA-instance.

Your example does have gcd of $P$ and $n$ equal to $1$.